# Zoom firefox to certain resolution

Tags: firefox, plugins

My page has a resolution of 800x480. It has been designed as such. Now in Firefox (I have control over the viewers machine), I want to zoom the whole screen to 800x600. I know that there is a zoom option, but that does it proportionally (e.g. 150%). Is it possible to somehow to only stretch the 480 to 600 (a sort of a zoom).

I have a valid reason to do this and am aware of the aspect ratio issues that could arise.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in Firefox 3.5 (Gecko 1.9.1) using CSS3 2d transforms.

Here's an example with two DIVs where the second is stretched from 800x480 to 800x600.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        html, body
        {
            background-color: #000;
            color: #fff;
        }
        .viewport
        {
            width: 800px;
            height: 480px;
            background-color: gold;
            color: #000;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
        }
        .stretched
        {
            background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
            -moz-transform: scaleY(1.25);
            -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="viewport"><button>Normal</button></div>
        <div class="viewport stretched"><br><br><button>Stretched</button></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

See also:

- [Using CSS transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
self.resizeTo(width, height);
```

Although I think Firefox has a default setting in the preferences which prevents this from working.

Comment: I don't want to resize the window. I want zoom it from 800x480 to 800x600.

Comment: So you want to stretch the content vertically?